# How do I change status Code with Vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Error handling with Vue-router seems to be easy, not until you look into the response code. As you can see the following, the 404 page displays a status code of 304, not 404 for a 'Not found' page.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cakKb.png)

I've looked up multiple threads, but it looks like not a single post implies this situation. Is this supposed to be handled with a web server like Nginx? If so, what about dynamic URLs that comes out in through API?

Ps. I am working with Vue-cli3.

Comment: It is not possible to use a HTTP 404 status code with a single-page application (a.k.a client-side routing). Once the page is loaded (and it certainly won't load if the server sends a 404 error) and your application is running - the point in time for sending HTTP status codes has passed away.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the HTTP status code from the JavaScript frontend. You'll have to let those HTTP calls go through to the server or redirect to a dedicated 404 page.